# Extracting the XML response instead of JSON in a RESTful API

Tags: xml, json, rest, soap, groovy

I am currently working on this REST API http://pokeapi.co as my practice for Groovy-REST. Right now i can get a specific JSON data from the REST response using SOAP UI 5.0 and make a simple output out of it. SOAP UI also produces an XML version of the JSON response. what i would like to know is, is it possible to use the returned XML instead of the JSON data? if so, how? i have been browsing for hours on ways how to do it but no luck

here's my current code:

```
@Grab(group='com.github.groovy-wslite', module='groovy-wslite', version='1.1.0')

import wslite.rest.*

class PokeApi {
    def restUrl = "http://pokeapi.co"
    def client = new RESTClient(restUrl)

    def getGameVer(def ver){
        def response = client.get(path: '/api/v1/game/' +ver+ '/')
        def result = ('Version Name: ' + response.json.name
                + '\nRelease Year: ' + response.json.release_year
                + '\nGame Generation: ' + response.json.generation
                )
        return result
    }

    def getPokemonInfo(def pokeID){
        def response = client.get(path: '/api/v1/pokemon/'+pokeID+'/')

        def pokeName = response.json.name
        def pokeNatID = response.json.national_id
        def ability1 = response.json.abilities[0].name
        def ability2 = response.json.abilities[1].name

        def result = ("Pokemon name: " + pokeName
                +"\nNationalID: " + pokeNatID
                +"\nAbility 1: " +ability1
                +"\nAbility 2: " + ability2)

        return result
    }



    static void main(String[] args){
        def poke = new PokeApi()
        def abc = poke.getGameVer(2)
        def bcd = poke.getPokemonInfo(399)
        println abc
        println bcd
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As You can [see](https://twitter.com/phalt_/status/542735468585304064) PokeAPI supports JSON format only. But I've found other online API and modified Your example a bit:

```
@Grab(group='com.github.groovy-wslite', module='groovy-wslite', version='1.1.0')

import wslite.rest.*

class ThomasBayerAPI {
    def restUrl = "http://www.thomas-bayer.com/"
    def client = new RESTClient(restUrl)

    def getCustomerInfo(def cid){
        def response = client.get(path: "/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/$cid")

        def id =  response.xml.ID
        def firstName = response.xml.FIRSTNAME
        def lastName = response.xml.LASTNAME
        def city = response.xml.CITY

        def result = ("Customer id: $id, firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName, city: $city")

        return result
    }

    static void main(String[] args){
        def api = new ThomasBayerAPI()
        def bcd = api.getCustomerInfo(3)
        println bcd
    }
 }
```

Basically the format of returned data is defined by `accept` header. With wslite You need to make a query in the following way:

```
def response = client.get(path: "/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/$cid", accept: ContentType.XML)
```

Unfortunately the API I found servers data only in XML. Can't find online API that returns data both in XML and JSON.

Comment: so is it the same way as how you extract json data like `response.json` and `response.xml` for xml?

Comment: i'll try out your code and see if it brings light to my question. thank you for your response

Comment: got your code running and made some tinkering and im starting to understand how it works. i think a few more tries with APIs that returns XML content will make me fully understand